# HBase reading slowing down after reading few miilion records

Tags: hbase, apache-kafka

I have batch job scheduled to load about 250 million records from HBase table to Kafka Queue.

The batch initially starts the scan or reading at about 1250 rows/sec. But after reading about 4 to 5 million records the read slows down to 90 rows/sec and maintains it forever.

I tried various ways to refresh the connection every 4 million records, but still it is slowing down.

Below is the configuration and logic for it.

```
private Configuration mHbaseConf;
private int MAX_HBASE_BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

private void hbaseConfCreation() {
    this.mHbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    this.mHbaseConf.setLong(HConstants.HBASE_RPC_TIMEOUT_KEY, 4000000);
    this.mHbaseConf.setLong(
            HConstants.HBASE_REGIONSERVER_LEASE_PERIOD_KEY, 3600000);
    this.mHbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", this.properties
            .getProperty("ip.hbase.zookeeper.quorum"));
    this.mHbaseConf
    .set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort",
            this.properties
            .getProperty("ip.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort"));
}
```

Below is the read and publish logic

```
HTable table = new HTable(this.mHbaseConf, tableName);
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setCaching(this.MAX_HBASE_BATCH_SIZE);
s.setCacheBlocks(false);
ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(s);

for (Result result : rs) {
    //prepare the value
    KafkaMsgPublisher.send(value);
}
```

The kafka message send happens instantly but the scan is the one that is slowing down. I have verified the same with the proper logs which shows the read consuming all the time.

I have this entire job single threaded iterating loop. I tried to reload the configuration every 4M records, that too didn't help.

This job will take days or months to complete like this. Is there any way I can improve this. What is the cause for this slow down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved last week. The issue was that I was having file write operation for storing the Key of the Hbase record. I was doing it for storing the Key incase of exception. The file write operation is not as fast as single Hbase record read and increased the time almost 100 fold.

```
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bufferWriter.write(rowKey);
        bufferWriter.write("\n");
        bufferWriter.close();
```

Once I commented this logic and moved it in the Catch block this job was very fast. About 200M records were all processed in below 12 hrs.